# Modificar Toolstripstatuslabel.Text de un formulario MDI padre desde otro hijo, y que solo lo haga el activo

Tags: vb.net

Básicamente tengo proyecto con formularios MDI, uno es **padre** y los demás **hijos** , la idea es que desde los **MDI hijo** puedan modificar el texto de un **toolstripstatuslabel** que forma parte de una barra de estado tiene el formulario padre. Lo difícil seria que solo el formulario activo, hijo, sea el que pueda realizar dicha acción y que los demás no puedan hacerlo.
Un ejemplo sería: tengo un proyecto similar al block de notas, el formulario padre contiene barra de estado de cuantas líneas tiene el documento activo, y hay tres formularios hijo contienen un textbox multilineal, cada uno contiene distinto texto. La idea es que se  muestre en su barra de estado la cantidad de líneas que tiene el texto del documento seleccionado o  formulario activo. Y cuando este se cambia la barra  actualice el dato correspondiente al seleccionado . 
Un código que pude hacer bastante básico es lo siguiente!
en formulario hijo:

> TryCast(Me.MdiParent, Form1).actualizarestado("funciona")

Y en el padre:

> Public Sub actualizarestado(texto As String)
>           toolstripstatuslabel.Text = texto
>       End Sub

El código funciona pero le falta la condición de activo, que solo el **ActiveMdiChild** sea el unico capas de modificar **toolstripstatuslabel.text**

Alguna idea?

Comment: eventos? pasarle al control a cada hijo?creo que tienes varias maneras de hacerlo...

Comment: y como harian los no activos para modificar la barra?

Comment: Cual seis ese evento? Activechild? Si pero como hacer que funcione , únicamente para el formulario activo? Hay algunas manera de hacerlo? No se me ha ocurrido más que lo que he planteado, me parece interesante poder lograr una comunicación más avanzada entre el formulado padre he hijo, un avance sería este para empezar, no se como lograrlo.

Comment: no entiendo esta frase de tu pregunta: El codigo funciona pero no es lo que necesito, que solo el ActiveMdiChild sea el unico capas de modificar toolstripstatuslabel.. a que te referis con el activo? si justamente el que llama es el activo? podrias dar un ejemplo concreto?

Comment: No entiendo el problema. Porque no compruebas en los formularios hijos si son el formulario activo antes de intentar modificar el texto en el padre?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontre esta solucion! una SUB global en un module. seria el siguiente:

```
Public Sub mostrarmensaje(formulariohijo As Form, mensaje As String, Optional fondo As Integer = 0)
    If System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms.Item(FORMULARIOPADRE.Name).ActiveMdiChild Is formulariohijo Then
        Dim informacion As ToolStripStatusLabel = DirectCast(formulariohijo.MdiParent, Sistema_TPV).informacionadicinallabel
        informacion.Text = mensaje
        Select Case fondo
            Case 1
                informacion.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
            Case 2
                informacion.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange
            Case 3
                informacion.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Donde dice "FORMULARIOPADRE" seria el formulario padre o bien el nombre del formulario padre. La sub es llamada por todos los formularios hijo, y solo funcionara los que estén activos! espero que a alguien le sirva!